Segmentation fault on action result callback
I am trying to write an action server to perform some action asynchronously. When the goal is completed the action server sends action_server_->succeeded_current(result); //Nav2 Util
The handler for this is added in the options for the action client when the request is sent.
send_goal_options.result_callback = std::bind(&class_name::result_callback, this, _1);
client->async_send_goal(goal, send_goal_options);

void class_name::result_callback(const GoalHandle::WrappedResult & result){
   //Perform actions
   //Control never enters this section of the code
}

I am not sure why there is this error, a similar architecture seems to work on other nodes but this one is crashing. Please let me know if any additional information is required. Thanks in advance!!
